# custom Date Range Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, momentjs

I am making a custom date range slider based of the github repository by [webangelo](https://github.com/webangelo/jQuery-Range-Calendar). His original version is great but only allows the user to drag the range slider one way and not the other. It also has some bugs that I am experiencing with the one I am trying to make.

I have uploaded my code to [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qeqordkk/3/) (run a few times if you see a grey circle). Originally the slider only has the east handle so I changed it to have west as well with `handles: "e, w"`. The event occurs in the didResizeBar code:

```
    obj.didResizeBar = function(e, ui) {


        var prevRangeWidth = obj.rangeWidth();
        var rangeWidth = prevRangeWidth;
        var resizeBarPos = obj.calendarObj.find('.range-bar').position();

        var resizeBarWidth = obj.calendarObj.find('.range-bar').outerWidth();
        var resizeBarRight = resizeBarPos.left+resizeBarWidth;
        var cellWidth = $(obj).find(".cell").first().outerWidth();
        var lastCellPos = $(obj).find(".cell").last().position();
        var deltaWidth = 0;
        var objWidth = (lastCellPos.left+cellWidth);

        if(resizeBarRight > objWidth){

            deltaWidth = objWidth-resizeBarWidth;
            prevRangeWidth = (resizeBarWidth-deltaWidth)/cellWidth;
        }

            obj.calendarObj.find('.cell').removeClass("selected");
            obj.calendarObj.find('.cell').removeClass("last");
            obj.calendarObj.find('.cell.start').addClass("selected");
            obj.calendarObj.find('.cell.start').nextAll().slice(0, (!rangeWidth ? obj.minRangeWidth-1 : rangeWidth-1)).addClass('selected');
            obj.calendarObj.find('.cell.selected').last().addClass("last");
            obj._dispatchEvent(obj.changeRangeCallback, obj.range(), obj);

    },
```

The problem with this now is that it doesn't update the highlighted dates to the left.

I've been trying to detect the change from pulling the west bar but the delta x and y variable i tried with (removed the code after) had the same values as pulling east.

With a `maxRangeWidth: 7,` the range bar extends out of you start from the left or right as well.

Is there any way to detect the change for the west bar and be able to change the start class from the current to the left if west bar is pulled?

Is it also possible to detect if it is reaching the last cell so it cannot extend past the last date slot?